# QGIS Roll over popup image sizing

Tags: qgis, popup

I am a couple of rungs on the ladder below junior novice in GIS. That said, I have a map, have about 100 lat/long points plotted on the map, and for those points for which I have pictures (typically 2 pictures per point).

When I  mouse roll over a point, the pictures and a brief text message pops up just as I want. However, to make this work sensibly, I had to re-save all of the pictures at a very low resolution, 100 - 200KB. If I left the pictures at their original 4 - 6 MB resolution, the screen would flood with a very zoomed in tiny portion of a picture.

Obviously re-saving everything is a solution, just not very elegant, so, how do I control the size of the popup window and make sure everything fits inside of it? And naturally some of the pictures are landscape, some portrait and the popup may have 2 landscape, 2 portrait or one of each.

Comment: You might want to add which version of QGIS you're using, on what OS and what you've done to get the pop-up to give potential helpers more background.

Comment: Of course: QGIS 2.14.10-Essen, Win 7 Pro, Using the Map Tips Icon

Answer (score 1):

If this is a map tip then you can add HTML which will allow you to style the image as you wish e.g:

```
<img src="[% path_to_image %]" width="100" height="200" />
```

Where path_to_image is an attribute containing the path and set the width and height to something sensible. You could control the width and height attributes as desired using attributes indeed anything you can build in the expression builder wrapped in [% ... %]

Comment: You're right about the quotes, edited answer to match, but the tag can be closed <img ..../> rather than <img></img>. This is more concise and avoid the temptation to put content between the opening and closing tags, which which would be invalid